# Python: Unknown Jinja error causing script not to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, jinja2, git-bash

I am trying to run the following python command: 
`$ python stack.py <file_name>` I am in the correct folder that holds the `stack.py` file.

However, I am getting the below error and I am not sure how to resolve it or why this is now happening.

I tried upgrading jinja `$ pip install Jinja2` with no luck.

I also reviewed the stack_error_vals.json and stack_error_template.j2 but it had no useful information in it.

Any ideas on how to resolve this so that my python command is successful again?

```
  File "stack.py", line 514, in proc_jinja_templates
    output = env.render(vals)
  File "C:\Users\jthomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jthomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Users\jthomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\jthomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<template>", line 16, in top-level template code
  File "C:/carbon\modules\templates\bridge\configs\config.xml.j2", line 27, in top-level template code
    {%- if v.required or ((v.configdatatype == 'Bool' and v.value in (true,false)) or (v.configdatatype == 'String' and v.value and 'changeme' not in v.value.lower())) -%}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'int object' has no attribute 'lower'

Writing stack_error_vals.json and stack_error_template.j2 for review
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template is assuming that `v.value` is a string, but in this case it's getting something which looks like an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'int object' has no attribute 'lower'
```

This means the thing you are trying to apply `.lower()` to is an integer rather than a string.

Without seeing your full code, you could try

```
str(v.value).lower()
```

Comment: in the config.xml.j2 file, line 27 has ```{%- if v.required or ((v.configdatatype == 'Bool' and v.value in (true,false)) or (v.configdatatype == 'String' and v.value and 'changeme' not in v.value.lower())) -%}```